# hostapd start error message

Tags: wireless, hostapd

Error Message

```
Configuration file: start
Could not open configuration file 'start' for reading.
Failed to set up interface with start
Failed to initialize interface
```

My Hostapd.conf file

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=wifigto
channel=1
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=alik060297
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Ubuntu 14.04 please help

Answer (score 6):

old but might help someone else:

open `/etc/default/hostapd`

uncomment `#DAEMON_CONF=""`

now add the path to config file; it should look like:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Comment: so as hostapd tells this is deprecated. configuration is no longer needed. tested with a raspberry pi zero w last month.

Comment: above fix still needed with hostapd version 2.6

Comment: It's not needed, unless you unmasked hostapd and are using it directly, instead of the new way with buster which is to name your configs and use it that way such as hostapd@ap0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the parameters in the command you are running wrong as its looking for a config file called "start".

Try replacing the "start" part of the command your running with the absolute path to the config file, for example

```
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Also be aware of the case of the file name, you said Hostapd.conf but its hostapd.conf by default.

Alternatively you could run it the normal way

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

Comment: Wow... I had my hostapd@ap0.service looking for /etc/hostapd/ap0.conf... but i named it `apd0.conf`. Fatigue is all over the forums for this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was very similar but slightly different:
it was pointing to the correct /ect/hostapd/hostapd.conf location where I expected the conf to be placed.

Even in the output of ls `/etc/hostapd` I just realized "yes the file is present". I didn't doublecheck each letter of the filename.

It was a typo. I named the file "hostapt.conf" by mistake, and didn't realize that. All other references were pointing to "hostapd.conf"

To avoid such typos, it's always good to check first what's the name of an application. "hostapd" means Host Access Point **Demon**

Unfortunately hostapd does not tell you that the file is *not present* - it just tells you it *can't read' the file*.

Comment: +1 for the good hint (often overlooked.)